# RecyclerView in CoordinatorLayout loses its top padding after orientation changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-support-design

I am using Support Design Library rev. 23.0.1 (and 22.2.1 as well). The problem is after activity orientation changes if RecyclerView (placed in fragment) has been scrolled, it loses its top padding which is probably equal to StatusBar Height + AppBar Height (as you see on a picture). [image]

[See this sample video](https://youtu.be/jbqVDymuI_g) for details

Here is my Activity layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/discount_activity_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.moskart.mosfake.widget.AppBarLayoutBehavior"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_title_margin_start"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="96dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/hero_image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:id="@+id/fragment"
                  android:name="com.moskart.mosfake.fragment.DiscountFeedFragment"
                  tools:layout="@layout/fragment_discount_feed"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And a simple fragment contains RecyclerView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.moskart.mosfake.fragment.DiscountFeedFragment"
>

<com.moskart.mosfake.widget.GridRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_discount_feed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />
```

By the way, I found some following issues, but these answers doesn't solve my problem. I've also tried approaches described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459212/3465776) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749188/3465776), but it has no effect, or I doing something wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add the code of your custom behavior com.moskart.mosfake.widget.AppBarLayoutBehavior ?